# Multiple file upload in PHP always drops first file

Tags: php, forms, file, upload

I am trying different examples of PHP multiple file upload like this one

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

    <div>
        <label for='upload'>Add files</label>
        <input id='upload' name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
    </div>

    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></p>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(count($_FILES['upload']['name']) > 0){
        //Loop through each file
        for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {
          //Get the temp file path
            $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

            //Make sure we have a filepath
            if($tmpFilePath != ""){
            
                //save the filename
                $shortname = $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

                //save the url and the file
                $filePath = $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

                //Upload the file into the temp dir
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath)) {

                    $files[] = $shortname;
                    //insert into db 
                    //use $shortname for the filename
                    //use $filePath for the relative url to the file

                }
              }
        }
    }

    //show success message
    echo "<h1>Uploaded:</h1>";    
    if(is_array($files)){
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($files as $file){
            echo "<li>$file</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}
?>
```

Problem is that it detects 3 files but uploads only 2 and the first one is always missing.
I don't get any error message so can't understand what is going on. I've tried some other samples of multi upload code but situation is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read this comment:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php#89674

And the files are not number `file0`, `file1`, `file2`, etc, but `file1`, `file2`, `file3`. It could be that the numeric indexes are also not  `0`, `1`, `2`, etc, but `1`, `2`, `3`, etc. So in your case you could correct for that by doing:

```
$tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i+1];
$shortname = $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i+1];
$filePath = $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i+1];
```

I haven't tested this, and I'm not at all sure about this, but it is easy for you to check it, just do a:

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```